# Load data from Mysql Database using Scala IDE in Spark framework

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this problem. IDE Scala gives me an error, because it says that `read` method in `sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(options)` does not belong to `SQLContext` object. Need I to add a dependency?

Then I do not know which library I need to add for the `DataFrame` and `Row` object.

This is the code.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;



public class caricaDati {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
    options.put("url",
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banche?user=..&password=...");
    options.put("dbtable", "t_analisi_banche_021");
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("DBConnection").setMaster("local[*]"));
    SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
    DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(options);
    System.out.println("Data------------------->" + jdbcDF.toJSON().first());
    Row[] rows = jdbcDF.collect();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext` instead? This class extends in good measure the functionality of `SQLContext`.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I have used  `import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;`  instead of  `import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;`. Moreover the instruction `DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(options);` was wrong. It should be `DataFrame jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(options).load();`